# How do we configure how many threads does the application spawn when using Task.Factory.StartNew

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, task-parallel-library

Is there any way to configure how many threads does the application spawn when using Task.Factory.StartNew ?

*Update*
I am just exploring the possibility of configuring the number of threads.

Comment: Part of the reason to use the Task library is to in essence remove that concern. Let the library handle that. In general, one call to StartNew runs one thread. StartNew launches a single action. What is your requirement or issue you are trying to resolve. If you are launching too many threads you can handle that with a semaphore.

Answer (score 3):

You would have to create a custom scheduler, there is in fact [a how to article on MSDN showing this specific case](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee789351.aspx).